# Mongoose/mongodb return null when user exists by id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

Im having trouble that my userid ( aka _id created by mongodb) wont let me search .

here is my user

```
db.users.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5912073cd87a401dd196a820"), "password" : "$2a$10$Sj/bxhSzeL8xzZYn8Vl71OjrG9Ayly9ueDi2O1iDwi7N4vYyZGWKi", "username" : "malin", "inFamily" : false, "bank" : 500, "defence" : 1, "attack" : 1, "cash" : -494055600, "xp" : 0, "rank" : 1, "bullets" : 0, "location" : 1, "permission" : 0, "health" : 0, "__v" : 0 }
```

as seen here its one with id `5912073cd87a401dd196a820` .

Here is the function im always calling.

```
function userDetails(userid) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                console.log("search: " + userid);
        // Users.findById(userid, function (result) {
Users.findOne({_id: userid},function(result) { 
            console.log("search done");
            console.log(result);
            return resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

I use the function all over my site, on some things its works, others it wont.
For example. when component 1 calls it it works, when component 2 tries, it fails.

None of the findByid or findOne works when its failing.

Here is the query my site ran on one of my components that is failing:

```
  search: 5912073cd87a401dd196a820
    Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5912073cd87a401dd196a820") }, { fields: {} })
    logging /api/gameapi?action=getcrimemembers
    navigate: false
    search done
    null
```

But every results is null/ false, how come?

Comment: what is this `{ fields: {} }` in your query? what are you trying to do here?

Comment: The users.findone function calls it. the mongoose fields is just how its query. the only thing im trying is to get the user based on the id.

Comment: try simple this `users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5912073cd87a401dd196a820") })` whether it works or not?

Comment: @node_saini wont work.

Comment: I don't think its the problem with your query. I guess it is something else may be the way you are querying or some connection issue or your function issue or function calling issue or something. Your whole code is not here so hard to debug.

Comment: You can run the query in mongo shell and see if you get data and if the query is right or not? Based on that you might be able to give the direction to your debugging either towards query or some application level issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this i'ts must work good. Mongoose function already returned promise so you don't need wrap it in function:

```
Users.findOne({_id: userid}).then(result=>{...}).catch(err=>{...})
```

Comment: but i do check the result, and its null ?